I2C communication with LCD screen via 2.5m long cable
I’m attempting to connect a 4x20 LCD to an Arduino Mega 2560 Rev3 using the I2C protocol via a 2.5m VGA cable. I understand that such a long cable isn’t ideal for I2C communication, but I cannot change this setup. I’ve reviewed a related question here, which was insightful, but I still have some doubts about how to make this work with my specific configuration.
My setup:

Microcontroller: Arduino Mega 2560 Rev3
I2C Expander: PCF8574 (remote 8-bit expander for I2C bus)
LCD: 20x4 HD44780-compatible
Cable: 2.5m VGA cable

SDA connected to pin 13
SCL connected to pin 14
GND connected to the VGA cable’s external sleeve


Libraries Used:

<Wire.h>
<hd44780.h>
<hd44780ioClass/hd44780_I2Cexp.h>



Questions:

Can I adjust the I2C clock frequency using the following code snippet without causing conflicts with the libraries used?
Wire.begin();
TWBR = 152;


Pull-up resistors:

I understand the Arduino Mega uses built-in 10k Ω pull-up resistors on the SDA and SCL lines. In my code, I didn’t explicitly configure SDA and SCL as pull-ups. I simply declared the LCD object like this:
hd44780_I2Cexp lcd; // declare lcd object: auto locate & auto config expander chip

Does the library’s auto-configuration automatically handle the pull-ups?

I’ve read that lower pull-up resistance is beneficial for longer cables. How can I modify the pull-up resistors on the Arduino Mega 2560? What resistance value would you recommend for this 2.5-meter cable?



Caps on SDA and SCL at the I2C expander end of the cable
Does it make sense to add 0.1 uF ceramic resistors between ground and SDA and ground and SCL?



If you really want lower pull up resistance, you can just put external pull-ups in parallel.  Making it bigger would be difficult.


Wire library has Wire.setClock(), read the doc. 2) Someone already answer this; 3) I2C stands for Inter-Integrated-Circuit protocol, meaning that it was design for short distance between ICs. If you really want to try 2.5m, as per I2C specification, the bus capacitance should not be higher than 200pf for fast mode. If you use a CAT 5 cable which has capacitance less than 52pf/m, with 2.2k pull-up and clock of 100kHz or lower, it might well within the I2C spec.


Since you mention VGA, do you know DDC? Its second version uses I²C... You might want to do some research. For example, it uses pins 12 and 15.

Any reason for not using the hardware I2C port on pins 20 and 21?

The problem with bus length is due to the way pull-ups work. For high-to-low transitions i2c node drives pin low, so the wire potential always falls fast. But for low-to-high transition the node goes to hi-z state instead. So the wire potential rises due to pull-up resistor only.
Now imagine that there is also some (parasitic) capacitor between wire and ground. Then the wire becomes a middle point for RC circuit. Therefore, its potential rise time becomes proportional to R multiplied by C. R is set by the spec between 1 and 10k. So if C is big enough then any low-to-high transition cannot be fast either.
So what are the options?

Reduce R. It's enough to add another pull-up resistor (so it's in parallel with existing one). Beware though not to make it too small and let the magic smoke out. Might be not a problem for SCL but SDA is always bidirectional.

2. Reduce C. Usually we just don't use long wires. In your case though you need to twist the wires one around another. Or just use good twisted pair cable.

Slow SCL speed. The spec sets 100kb/s as the slowest clock speed. However, only the host decides what the real speed is. The slaves might be missing too fast clocks but usually they don't have any problems with slow ones. Of course, hardware/library implementations may not support such feature. But making i2c bit-banging implementation is really trivial. Then you can make clock as slow as you need.

Using bidirectional buffer(s) in the middle of your cable. That's a bit controversial advice as a buffer will create a delay of its own. But I guess it doesn't hurt to experiment with. If some cheap "logic level shifter" module can't help then, maybe, some dedicated ic (txs010x etc.) will do better. Who knows?

Desolder i2c board and drop i2c bus completely. The screen itself is not bound to i2c protocol. You can attach, say, 74hc595 instead and switch to SPI (which is also short distance thing but should work for 2-3 meter cable). Or simply draw all (eight or so) wires in parallel without any fancy serial-to-parallel protocol stuff. Maybe you'll need also some buffer chips, maybe not. In the worst case some UART based solution could resolve virtually any trouble with cable length/quality.




On Reduce C, twist pair does not reduce C. The Capacitance is determined by the tray capacitance of the PCB and the type of the wire. Twist pairs do not help I2C (or digital signalling) as both SDA and SCL are ground-referenced, and it would not be beneficial to twist the SCL and SDA wires together as this would increase crosstalk between them. 2) Hardware I2C doe not necessary operate at 100kHz, even you configure the I2C as 100kHz, you often found that the actual clock speed could be as low as 80kHz depend on MCU's clock configuration and internal prescaler.


@hcheung 1. Twisting signals with gnd, as i2c devices need common ground and no one likes having a separate cable for it; 2. If it works for 100 or for 80 then it's okay; the point is that the bus master could set even much lower speed if only software allows for it.

Twist with GND will only increase the capacitance, not reduce it. Twist pair improve EMI (for analog signal) but the issue with I2C protocol is the capacitance of the line (<200pf for fast mode). Read the I2C protocol specification.
